# Burn and Uninstall shortcut

Tags: wpf, wix, burn, wix3.7

We create an installation .exe with burn that successfully installs .NET4 as a prerequisite and our .msi which was created with a wix script. All this works quite well.

Our wix script creates an uninstall shortcut (pretty much taken from the wix how-to pages):

```
<Shortcut Id="UninstallProduct" 
         Name="Uninstall Product Name" 
         Target="[SystemFolder]msiexec.exe" 
          Arguments="/x [ProductCode]" 
          Description="Uninstalls Product" />
```

If I use this shortcut, the application is correctly uninstalled and all relevant files are removed. However, the entry in the  installed programs table in "Programs and Feature" is still there. I also notice that it is not the burn UI that comes up if I use the uninstall shortcut. Basically, my question is: How can I create an uninstall shortcut that removes the entry in the Programs and Features table when using burn?